# Python 3.7 - UnicodeEncordeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 25: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, request

I'm using Pycharm to run this script to scrape data from a webpage and save it to a text file.
The text format on the webpage and in the text file is identical (As if I manually use ctr-A, copy & paste the content of the webpage to an empty text file).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.hkgem.com/statistics/daily/e_G201201.htm'
header = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'}
print("Requesting data from HKGEM...")
url_obj = requests.get(url, headers=header)
print("Status : ", url_obj.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_obj.content, "html5lib")
file_name = "GEM_stock_data.txt"
file = open(file_name, 'w')
file.write(soup.text)
file.close()
```

Now, every time I run the script, it takes me a long time to print this message on my console

```
Status :  200
```

And then, I have this error message

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 25: character maps to <undefined>
```

I tried changing the line to

```
file = open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8')
```

Then, the text file contains a bunch of weird symbols.

Is there a way I can code to speed up printing the `Status: 200` message?

Also, what can I try next to get rid of the `UnicodeEncodeError`? Thank you.

Comment: You did the right thing by opening the file with `utf-8`, but it looks like whatever editor you're using to look at the file doesn't recognize the encoding properly.

Comment: @MarkRansom I am using the text document that comes with win 7. Is there any setting I need to change?

Comment: If the file is opening with `Notepad` that would explain it.  `Notepad++` is a replacement with more options.

Answer (score 1):

If "a long time" means a few seconds, that's normal for fetching a web page. I just fetched it, and it took a bit over 2 seconds.

If you have been fetching the same page repeatedly, it is quite possible that the server is throttling you, i.e. serving the content much slower than for a new visitor. Some sites do this to discourage scraping or bandwidth hogging.

The page contains a `meta` header which indicates `charset=ansi`.  This is not a valid character set identifier; probably this bogus header is throwing off BeautifulSoup and causing it to replace some characters with the Unicode "unknown character" glyph [U+FFFD](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).  You can override the encoding with

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(url_obj.content, from_encoding='ascii')
```

(or whatever; try e.g. `'latin-1'` if `'ascii'` doesn't work; in the general case, you need to understand encodings and identify the correct one. A recommended starting point is Joel Spolsky's seminal introduction [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/))

Comment: Going forward, please ask _one_ question per question, please.